# How malloc array in struct in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have struct:

```
typedef struct akcie
{
    int *stockArray;
} AKCIE;
```

Declaration

```
 AKCIE *idStock;
```

Malloc idStock

```
idStock = ( AKCIE *)malloc( id * sizeof( int )); // id is an integer
```

Now I want to malloc to every idStock[i], i = 1,2,3,..... stockArray in function, etc. void(parameters) { malloc every idStock[i].stockArray; }.

How to alloc idStock[0], idStock[1] in function? I dont know how to transmit the struct as parameter. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can alloc the memory for each of the elements in the struct.

This is the procedure:

```
void procedure(AKCIE *idStock, int n){ //n is the dim
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
          idStock[i].stockArray = (int *)malloc(HOW_MANY_DO_YOU_NEED * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
```

and this is how you call it:

```
    .
    .
    .
    procedure(idStock, dim);
    .
    .
    .
```

PS: there is an error in your allocation of memory for idStock. It does not contains `int`, but `int *`.

To avoid this kind of mistakes you can just pass the whole structure to the function `sizeof()`.

Comment: Thank you, that is it, what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Two `malloc`s are required.  One for the `AKCIE` array and another for each `int` array.  Below is an example for statically sized arrays:

```
#define STRUCT_ARRAY_DEPTH (10)
#define INT_ARRAY_DEPTH    (20)

int i;
AKCIE *idStock;

idStock = malloc(STRUCT_ARRAY_DEPTH * sizeof(*idStock));
for(i = 0; i < STRUCT_ARRAY_DEPTH; i++)
    idStock[i].stockArray = malloc(INT_ARRAY_DEPTH * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
idStock = ( AKCIE *)malloc( id * sizeof( int ));
```

Assuming `idStock` is to be treated as an array, and `id` is the length of that array, you're not allocating the proper amount of space.  You're only allocating space for a number of `int` variables, but the struct contains an `int *`, which may not be the same size.

What you want is this:

```
idStock = ( AKCIE *)malloc( id * sizeof( AKCIE ));
```

This allocates an array of `AKCIE`s of length `id`.  Once you do this, you don't need to allocate the individual array members, since it's already done.

Comment: Ok, you are right. It means, if id = 1, sizeof( AKCIE ) is 8, idStock will be idStock[0] ..... idStock[7]?

Comment: @Levin Not sure what you mean by that.  Are you suggesting that `sizeof(AKCIE)` is dependent on the value of `id`?  Because that's not true.  The value of `sizeof(AKCIE)` is a constant.

Comment: I mean, it creat id * sizeof(AKCIE) places in array. For id = 1, it creat 8 places.

Comment: @Levin No, it doesn't create 8 places.  It creates a space of 8 **bytes**, which is big enough for a 1 element array.  So `idStock[0]` would be the only valid element in that case.  If you want 8 elements then set `id` to 8.